# I am trying to invoke gradle from cronjob, but it doesn't seem get executed

Tags: java, bash, gradle, cron

I just installed gradle on my MacBook, and want to invoke share.sh from cronjob as bellow:

```
16 22 * * * /workspace/ShareMyData/share.sh > /dev/null
```

And the share.sh uses gradle to execute java code for Google data sharing.
Here is the share.sh script snippet.

```
#!/bin/bash 

PWD=`pwd`
# change to gradle project home
cd /workspace/ShareMyData
gradle -q run
cd $PWD
```

The share.sh was invoked by the cronjob properly, however there was no sign of "gradle" command gets executed; I also ran the share.sh directly from command line, everything worked as expected. 
I have no idea why gradle cannot get executed in my script from cronjob. Please help on this and thanks in advance.

Comment: Added `which gradle` to your script, run it through cron, and see what you get.  This seems like a `$PATH` setting issue.

Comment: Btw.: If this is your complete script, you can omit all lines which contain `PWD`.

Comment: @Cyrus Can `PWD` lines be omitted because the script runs in a subshell, and doesn't affect any other shell's current working directory?

Comment: @GeorgePantazes: yes.

Answer (score 1):

Commands ran on your shell may behave differently when running it inside cron. Try to put the actual path of gradle in your script.

```
/path/to/gradle -q run
```

You can find the actual path using the **which** command from your shell.

```
which gradle
```

Comment: Indeed that's the root cause. By modifying it like this in my script
/usr/local/bin/gradle -q run
It runs perfectly from cronjob.  
Thanks a lot!